# Translate {{if @last}} handlebars templates to vue 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to progressively switch from Backbone + Handlebars to Vue, but I am having some troubles with Handlebars templates.

In one of my templates I have something like this:

```
{{#each tHeads}}
  {{#if @last}}
    {{#each th}}
      {{#if iWidth}}
        <col style="width: {{iWidth}}px;"/>
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

I want to translate this to a vue template, but cannot find the corresponding for @last helper from Handlebars.

Comment: See also the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740105/vue-check-if-you-are-on-the-last-prop-of-a-v-for-loop

Answer (score 2):

There is no implementation for something like `@last` in Vue, as Evan You explained [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1842) that it will be costly to have such feature which are also used not that frequently for each `v-for` loop.

You can define a method `isLast` for this and use it like following:

```
<div v-if="isLast(index)">
```

**JS**

```
methods: {
  isLast (index) {      
    return this.list.length === index + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it!

Comment: @bboydflo It is advised to AVOID using methods directly in the templates as they are executed on every change detection cycle. Instead, try using a computed property