# Vue - check if you are on the last prop of a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, v-for

If I have the following data property:

```
person: {name: 'Joe', age: 35, department: 'IT'}
```

And wanted to loop through and output it as follows:

```
name: Joe, age: 35, department: IT
```

So far I have:

```
<span v-for="(val, key) in person">{{key}}: {{val}}, </span>
```

But this displays:

```
name: Joe, age: 35, department: IT,
```

with an extra comma on the end, how can I have it detect that it's the last prop and not show the comma? I thoughta v-show or v-if may be the solution but can't quite figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/41761831/1610034

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Here is one way.

```html
<span v-for="(val,key,index) of person">
  key: {{key}}, val: {{val}}, index: {{index}}
  <span v-if="index != Object.keys(person).length - 1">, </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 66):

Here's a solution if you're looping through an array, rather than an object:

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <div v-if="index == items.length - 1">yes</div>
    {{ item }}, {{ index }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 61):

You can also "cheat" by inserting the comma before each item, as it's easier to check for the **first** item (`index !== 0`).

```html
<span v-for="(val, key, index) in person">
  <span v-if="index !== 0">, </span>
  {{key}}: {{val}}
</span>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the goal of getting the "last" item in the array. It only gets the "not first" item.

Comment: This solution should work, dont agree with TetraDev.  This solution simply doesnt show the , for the first entry.  But it does show all other entries with a comma before.  Good and simple solution.

Comment: I dont even think this is cheating :)

Comment: Works great, if you can not easily determine .length.

Comment: This is great, got me thinking about the problem a bit differently; the best logic is that which can be removed altogether.

Comment: Can shorten it down a bit more `<span v-if="!index">, </span>`

Comment: mtpultz, even shorter `<span v-if="index">, </span>`

Answer (score 21):

You can do that with a `computed` to see if the current index (third parameter for`v-if`) is the last property:

```
computed: {
  last(){
     return Object.keys(this.person).length-1;
  }
}
```

Then in your `v-for`:

```
<span v-for="(val, key, index) in person">{{key}}: {{val}}<span v-if="index !== last">, </span> </span>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wv2ujxvn/

Answer (score 14):

This also works:

```html
<span v-for="(value,key) in persons" :key='key'>
    {{key}}: {{val}} 
    <span v-if="key+1 != persons.length">, </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 8):

A pity there is no shortcut provided by Vue.

I personally prefer using a small CSS:

```html
<div class="list">
  <span>Item 1</span>
  <span>Item 2</span>
  <span>Item 3</span>
</div>
```

```sass
.list span:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: ',';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store the knowledge about this pattern in code instead of on Stack Overflow, you could create a component like this:

```html
<template>
  <span v-if="show"><slot></slot></span>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'separator',
    props: ['items', 'index'],
    computed: {
      show () {
        return this.index !== (Array.isArray(this.items) ? this.items : Object.keys(this.items)).length - 1
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

This doesn't necessarily make the code shorted, but easier to remember:

```html
<span v-for="(val, key, index) of person">key: {{key}}, val: {{val}} 
  <separator :items="person" :index="index">, </separator>
</span>
```