# Add key event to last item of v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I select the last item of a v-for and give it a keydown event like this:

```
@keydown.tab.exact = "closeMenu"
```

I want to close the submenu if the user presses TAB on the last item of it, so it can navigate to the next submenu.

This is the code of the submenu:

```
<li
        v-for="(item, index) in menuItems[0]"
        :key="index"
        tabindex="-1"
        @keydown.shift.tab="closeSubMenu"
        @keyup.enter.exact="closeSubMenu"
        @keyup.tab.exact="closeSubMenu">

        <nuxt-link
          :to="item.url"</nuxt-link>
</li>
```

So far there are two items in this array and I don't know how to approach this in the vue way

Comment: could do a couple of ways, one way is to pass the index to closeSubMenu and check if its the last one, another way is to move the v-for up so you could do v-if on the items to see if its the last one

Comment: Related: [Vue - check if you are on the last prop of a v-for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740105/vue-check-if-you-are-on-the-last-prop-of-a-v-for-loop)

Comment: I used Object.keys, but for some reason I can't figure out, it adds the event listener in the moment it gets focused. Therefore it dissapears when I TAB to it, I will try with index.

Answer (score 0):

No other way but to move your event on child pass index as param

```
<li
        v-for="(item, index) in menuItems[0]"
        :key="index"
        tabindex="-1"
        
        @keyup.enter.exact="closeSubMenu"
        @keyup.tab.exact="closeSubMenu">
        
        <div v-for="(val, key, index) of item">
           <nuxt-link :to="item.url" @keydown.shift.tab="closeSubMenu(index)" v-if="key == 'url'"></nuxt-link>
        </div>
        
</li>
```